# explode string to a multi array with 2 delimiter

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this kind of sting i variable in php:

```
 $hccRol = GA#COR,OP#COR,FOR#TB,GA#LTS,FOR#MOD,GA#PMAI,LDR#LID,HCC#LAD,HN#LAD,OP#LAD,GA#LAD,GA#WM,OP#WM,HN#WM,OP#VZ,HN#VZ,GA#VZAI
```

I want convert this to multi array that look somthing like this:

```
Array ( [GA] => Array ( [1] => COR 
                        [2] => LTS 
                        [3] => LAD 
                        [4] => WM 
                        [5] => VZAI 
                      )
        [FOR] => Array( [1] => TB
                        [2] => MOD
                      )
        [OP] => Array(  [1] => COR
                        [2] => WM
                        [3] => VZ
                      )
)
```

So the # determines in witch primary array the value must come

Comment: Can you share what you have tried with us?

Comment: Explode at `,`, loop over results, split each one at `#`, and then simply push to the array by using first part as key and second as value … rather trivial. (Apart from the index starting with 1 instead of the “normal” 0 – if you explicitly need that, you will have to take an extra step.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBroe gave you the steps to do it the traditional way, so just for fun because I was bored:

```
parse_str(str_replace(array('#',','), array('[]=','&'), $hccRol ), $result);
print_r($result);
```

PHP >= 5.4.0:

```
parse_str(str_replace(['#',','], ['[]=','&'], $hccRol ), $result);
```

Comment: Thanks is think to complete, with foreach loop or something like that

Answer (score 0):

The following is a basic way to explode on the delimiting characters, iterate the data, and declare the new array structure.  I will honor your desired output and start the keys at `1` instead of the standard `0`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VdN4R))

```
$hccRol = "GA#COR,OP#COR,FOR#TB,GA#LTS,FOR#MOD,GA#PMAI,LDR#LID,HCC#LAD,HN#LAD,OP#LAD,GA#LAD,GA#WM,OP#WM,HN#WM,OP#VZ,HN#VZ,GA#VZAI";

foreach (explode(",", $hccRol) as $item) {
    $halves = explode("#", $item, 2);
    if (!isset($result[$halves[0]])) {
        $result[$halves[0]][] = null;  // add zero key placeholder element
    }
    $result[$halves[0]][] = $halves[1];
    unset($result[$halves[0]][0]);     // remove the placeholder element
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'GA' => 
  array (
    1 => 'COR',
    2 => 'LTS',
    3 => 'PMAI',
    4 => 'LAD',
    5 => 'WM',
    6 => 'VZAI',
  ),
  'OP' => 
  array (
    1 => 'COR',
    2 => 'LAD',
    3 => 'WM',
    4 => 'VZ',
  ),
  'FOR' => 
  array (
    1 => 'TB',
    2 => 'MOD',
  ),
  'LDR' => 
  array (
    1 => 'LID',
  ),
  'HCC' => 
  array (
    1 => 'LAD',
  ),
  'HN' => 
  array (
    1 => 'LAD',
    2 => 'WM',
    3 => 'VZ',
  ),
)
```

If you are happy to have the `0` indexes, then just remove the `if{}` block and the `unset()` line.